# Run as a different user from SYSTEM account

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have access to the system account but instead I want to open "notepad" in another user account but I don't want to write the password of the others users cuz I'm the admin. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Short answer: no, you must provide the password to run as a different user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use cached credentials in this case.
You can run notepad from powershell with encrypted stored credentials.

Run these lines to create a cached credentials file.

```
<# Set and encrypt credentials to file using default method #>

$credential = Get-Credential
$credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content c:\scripts\encrypted_password1.txt
```

Use the cached creds:

```
$username = "account"
$encrypted = Get-Content c:\scripts\encrypted_password1.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($username, $encrypted)

Start-Process notepad.exe -Credential $credential
```

Please store encrypted password file in a safe folder protected by NTFS permissions from viewing by other users.

Another solution is to compile script as exe file with built-in credentials. You can do this with free [ps2exe powershell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ps2exe/).

Comment: This solution is the most acceptable approach. Still open for more solution. My plan was to minimize the interaction with clients. Just get into the system. Execute and ask them if everything was fixed. But I'll check how to work this out with this script